# VS2017 clone git repo and map to Team menu

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, tfs-2015

We have TFS 2015 with set of git repos. I cloned one of them by git itself via 'git clone ...'. It worked good with VS2017. I could push and pull for remote origins. However when I hit 'Team' menu I see only 'Manage connections'. It looks like VS2017 didn't recognized that I connected. When I try connect to git repo VS2017 closes my curernt solution and wants me clone repo first, but I already copied.

**The question is how map already cloned git repo to VS2017, thus it recognize that repo is cloned and I can use some TFS features ?**

It looks like VS2017 does understand that repo was cloned previously. It only understand if it was copied from VS2017 itself.

**Update1**
My steps are:

1. I cloned repo '***CloudService' via cmd executing 'git clone' command. Thus I have local git repo . When I open VS I see this repo under 'Local Git Repositories'
   [image: have cloned local repo]
2. I hit  "Manage Connections -> Connect To Project". Opened dialog "Connect to a Project". I select my repo and see message "Cloned locally at...". path is correct, I assume VS map my cloned repo to TFS. Lastly hit "Connect" button.
   [image: Connect to a project]
3. Next thing I see Team Explorer tab where VS wants me clone this repo to default path. Looks like VS forgot that I already copied it.

If I change path to already copied repo and hit "Clone" button VS warns me "The folder d:\work***CloudService\ already exists and is not empty.Choose a new folder or an empty folder for the cloned repository.". I don't need this.

[image]

4. Restarting VS. Open Team Explorer tab. I see that VS still wants me to clone repo. 
   [image]
5. Ok. let's copy to different path. I change to empty folder and hit "Clone" I get new copy of repo. (On this step sometimes I saw that VS after cloned repo doesn't recognized that it did it, thus restart VS helped)
   [image]

Finally I haven't mapped my local copied repo to TFS and cloned into another folder. Since I know about such "feature" of VS, I supposed to clone all repos by VS. 
My question was what I'm doing wrong to map already existed repo to TFS.

P.S. VS2017 version
[image]

Comment: After adding local repository in VS 2017> Manage Connection in team explorer> Connect to project>Select TFS, collection, project, then repository> Check the location in Cloned locally at input box (cloned by command)> Connect.

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT, but when I specified already cloned local repo path and hit "connect" buton in the dialog I see Team Explorer tab with "clone" button. VS2017 doesn't recognize that I already cloned repo, I just need connect local repo to TFS only. When I clone everything via VS2017 it works. (However sometimes it doesn't recognize cloned repo too, need to restart VS).

Comment: Do you mean it works fine after restarting VS? On the other hand, could you provide the detail steps, we will check it.

Comment: The steps are correct. Try to clear client cache of TFS and try again (path like C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0) On the other hand, could you reproduce this issue on other machine?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the local repo first, then manage the connection.

Please follow below steps to use the pre-cloned Git repo:

1. Navigate to custom repo location > Git clone (E:\Andy\GirRepo for example):

   `git clone http://server:8080/tfs/collectionlc/_git/Git-Scrum`
2. Click **Manage Connections** icon in **Team Explorer**
3. Click **Add** under **Local Git Repositories** to add the cloned
   local repo (E:\Andy\GirRepo\Git-Scrum)
4. Double click the new added local repo (Git-Scrum), then open the solution.
5. Manage the Connection, connect to the project

**Update:**

If that not works for you, you can try to Remove the Git repo first, then follow above steps to clone and add a new local repo again to check that.

Besides, it seems a sync issue, just try to clean the client caches（both for TFS and VS),  then restart VS and try it again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't work. May be I wrote to messy...I cloned git repo and created it locally. I have it under Local Git Repositories, I can push and pull, but. When I press Team menu I see only 'Manage Connections...' menu. If I make local copy the same repo via VS2017, it works good. I open solution and see full menu starting with "New Work Item" and others.  Thus if you want work with VS2017 and have connection to TFS you need make copy of git repo from VS2017 instead of 'git clone'

Comment: @Alezis Yes,I tested that, after adding the Local Git Repository, then open the solution which located in the new added repo, then Team > Manage connections to connect to TFS, it works at my side. If that not works for you , you can try to Remove the Git repo first, then follow the steps in above answer to clone and add a new local repo again to check that. Also you can try to clean the client caches.